# Do observers need to be removed in iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I subclass MPMoviePlayerController. In that class I attached all possible notifications that I need. `DidFinishPlayback`, `ExitFullScreen` etc. in it's loading method. My question is, if I want to STOP movie and dismiss movie player view can I (and do I need to) remove observers in `moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange` method on `stateStopped`? What can happen if I don't do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important place to remove an observer of any kind is in the dealloc method. It is best practice to remove the observers as soon as your done observing but absolutely needs to be done by dealloc.

The reason for this is because if you register as an observer for something and your class gets deallocated the object you were observing could possible try and callback to the now deallocated object. More than likely this will cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and close your application.

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily a "best practice" to tie observer lifetime to the lifetime of the object: It _is_ imperative to unregister an object as an observer before it dealloc's, though.

Comment: I never said to tie it to the lifetime of the object. I recommended to stop observing once you are done with the object. And I implied that is imperative to do by dealloc. :) "It is best practice to remove the observers as soon as your done observing"